# Getting wrong value from cursor.getInt() in ViewBinder

Tags: android

I have a ListFragment in my android app that gets data from my sqlite db.

The Layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_fav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample Data"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_fav"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_verz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Verzeichnis:"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_fav"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_folder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample Data"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_verz"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ImageView iv_fav, is clickable and should update the database value. If its 1 it should get 0, and otherwise.
I wanted to use this code for that:

```
private void displayListView(View view) {

    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllBooks();

    String[] columns = new String[] {
        BookDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,
        BookDbAdapter.KEY_FOLDER,
        BookDbAdapter.KEY_FAV
    };

    int[] to = new int[] {
        R.id.tv_title,
        R.id.tv_folder,
        R.id.iv_fav
    };

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.single_row_item, cursor, columns, to, 0);

    dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, final Cursor cursor, final int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(BookDbAdapter.KEY_FAV)) {
                view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int columnIndexId = cursor.getColumnIndex(BookDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
                        int columnIndexFav = cursor.getColumnIndex(BookDbAdapter.KEY_FAV);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "star clicked! " + cursor.getInt(columnIndexId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        int starred = 0;
                        if (cursor.getInt(columnIndexFav) == 0) {
                            starred = 1;
                            ImageView img = (ImageView) v;
                            img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_on));
                        } else {
                            ImageView img = (ImageView) v;
                            img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_off));
                        }
                        dbHelper.setFav(cursor.getInt(columnIndexId), starred);
                    }
                });
                ImageView img = (ImageView) view;
                if (cursor.getInt(4) == 1) {
                    img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_on));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_off));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

The problem now is, that cursor.getInt(columnIndexId) does not give me the correct ID from the database. Do I click the first item, that has the id of 1 in the db, I get 12 back. Same the second item, should be 2, but I get 12. The third item, should be 3, I get 12. Do I go further in my List, like the 10th item, i get a 16 back, than a few items later an 18, and so on...

Why is that? What did I do wrong? I really dont get it...

Comment: Is this probably a problem with the view.setOnClickListener() inside the setViewValue Method?

Comment: derolli, Yes, my problem is this. Please help me.